# Flex children not wrapping in Internet Explorer 11

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, flexbox

I have spent hours trying to fix this issue in IE11 with no luck. I need to use css Flex to group tabs on a page and give a heading to each tab group.

This works without issues in Chrome/Firefox. When there is extra space to the write of tabs, they don't wrap and **they don't take 100% of width**, **unless** they need it.

And they wrap nicely when window size is small:

[image: Chrome screenshot]

But in IE tab texts are not wrapping.

[image: IE screenshot]

I would appreciate any help on this.

This is a sample page very similar to what I'm working with. (I should note I did manage to get the tabs to wrap in IE at some point but then the tabs were expanding to fill up 100% of screen which I'm not supposed to have.

```
<style>

tabSection {
    display: flex;
}



h3 {
    padding: 10px; border: 1px solid gray;
}

.tabGroup {
    display: flex; align-items: flex-end;
}
.header {
    flex: 1 0 auto; text-align: center
}
.tabGroupParent {
    display: flex; flex-direction: column; border: 3px solid green
}

.tab {
   flex: 0 1 auto;
}
</style>

<div class="tabSection">

<div class="tabGroupParent" >
    <span class="header">header</span>
    <div class="tabGroup" >

        <h3 class="tab">
            column value stuff stuff 1
        </h3>
        <h3 class="tab">
            column value stuff stuff 2
        </h3>
        <h3 class="tab">
            column value stuff stuff 3
        </h3>

    </div>
</div>
<div class="tabGroupParent" >
    <span class="header">header</span>
    <div class="tabGroup">

        <h3 class="tab">
            column value stuff stuff 4
        </h3>

    </div>
</div>
```

added codepen link
https://codepen.io/Oboluse/pen/mmNaoR

[codepen screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EGiFG.png)

Can you please remove the duplicate mark from this question. This is a different problem and does not get solved by adding width:100% to children elements in this case.

Interestingly, if I remove flex-direction: column; from .tabGroupParent child elements start wrapping in IE. But I'm not sure how else to achieve the Header look without using flex-direction:column here.

Comment: is this your layout? https://codepen.io/anon/pen/eWqbOV seems like it behaves the same for me in ie11 and chrome

Comment: this is the layout. The parent Div (class=tabSection) was missing from yours https://codepen.io/Oboluse/pen/mmNaoR

Comment: I've tried adding weight:100% to child elements as mentioned in other posts but it didn't fix the issue.

Comment: if you tried the solutions in the post this was flagged as a dupe of, you can try making a new post